# How to determine which stream end point is at the basin outlet?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, watershed

I am working with streams, stream end points, elevation raster and I have created basins using the watershed tool in ArcGIS.  From that data, I would like to determine for each basin, which single point is at or nearest the outlet as shown by the arrow in the example below.

[image]

Comment: If this is a diagram of stream order (eg Strahler) which has been developed already, wouldn't it be implicit that it is already the outlet, since it will be assigned the highest Strahler value? More background is required to your question.

Comment: Those are just streams with no order information.

Comment: Wouldn't this always be the lowest end point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the largest flow accumulation point . (you could have several lowest points due to your DEM resolution).

1. use zonal statistics to identify the maximum flow accumulation
   inside your basin
2. use "Con" to find the pixel of your basin that is equal to this
       maximum value
3. convert the result to point

Comment: Yes this works the majority of the time.  Good enough for me.